# Validate us number with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm doing an exercise on freecodecamp for validate us telephone number.

The user may fill out the form field any way they choose as long as it is a valid US number. The following are all valid formats for US numbers:

> 555-555-5555, (555)555-5555, (555) 555-5555, 555 555 5555, 5555555555, 1 555 555 5555

I'm using RegEx to test input.I type these expression on regex101

```
(([1]\s)?(\()*(\d{3})(-|\)|\)\s|\s)*(\d{3})(-|\s)*\d{4})
```

to test input like:

2 ** (757) 622-7382** return true

-**1 (757) 622-7382** return true

10 ** (757) 622-7382** return true

How could I test the leading 2, minus sign and 10.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you want to make sure that the field only contains a phone number and nothing else, you should start the regexp with `^` (matches start of string) and end it with `$` (matches end of string). All three examples would then return true, since they have something in front of the valid phone number.

Comment: thanks @Anders I figure it out

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit late but here is the solution to this one.

```
/^(1\s?)?(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[\s\-]?\d{3}[\s\-]?\d{4}$/;
```

You do want to have the ^ at the beginning of the expression to match the first char of the string and you want to use $ at the end to let the expression know that this is the end.

You can see the above answer and another way of doing it on the following github [github link](https://github.com/FreeCodeCamp/FreeCodeCamp/wiki/Algorithm-Validate-US-Telephone-Numbers)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have a look on [OWASP Validation Regex Repository](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Validation_Regex_Repository) as they are subject of validation and continuous updates

For the US Phone (at the time I'm writing)the suggested RegEx is `^\D?(\d{3})\D?\D?(\d{3})\D?(\d{4})$`

Answer (score 0):

`((-)?\d{0,2} )?` Notice the `space` after `{0,2}`

```
(-)?       // may begin with a minus
(\d{1,2})?   // may have 1 or 2 digits before the actual number
( )?       // may have a space after that
```

[DEMO](http://www.regexr.com/3bblr)

Comment: I want to make sure the phone number start with 1 XXX XXX XXXX or only XXX XXX XXXX.
and i figure out by changing my expression to
^(([1](\s)?)?(\()*(\d{3})(-|\)|\)\s|\s)*(\d{3})(-|\s)*\d{4})$
 thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of your regex that will now match the new phone formats:

```
^[-+]?(?:\d{1,2}\s)?\(*(?:\d{3})(?:-|\)|\)\s|\s)*\d{3}(?:-|\s)*\d{4}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gX1yC0/1)

Note I removed the capture groups (I doubt you need them, and they create additional overhead) and added optional `+` or `-` before the number.
Also, `\d{1,2}` matches *1 or 2 digits* due to the [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{1,2}`.

Answer (score 0):

This works too

```
function telephoneCheck(str){
  const regEx = /^((1\s*)(([(]\d{3}[)])|(\d{3}))|([(]\d{3}[)])|(\d{3}))(\s*|\-)\d{3}(\-|\s*)\d{4}$/g

  if (regEx.test(str)) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```